# Accessing a nonmember function of a derived class from a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, membership

I'm trying to call a nonmember function of a derived class from a base class, but getting this error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'generate_vectorlist(const char&)'

Here's the relevant code snippets from the base class:

```
//Element.cpp
#include "Vector.h"
    ...

string outfile;
cin >> outfile;
const char* outfile_name = outfile.c_str();
generate_vectorlist(*outfile_name); //ERROR
...
```

and the derived class (this is a template class, so everything's in the header):

```
//Vector.h 
    template <class T>
void generate_vectorlist(const char* outfile_name = "input.txt" )
{
    std::ofstream vectorlist(outfile_name);
    if (vectorlist.is_open())
        for (Element::vciter iter = Element::vectors.begin(); iter!=Element::vectors.end(); iter++) 
        {
            Vector<T>* a = new Vector<T>(*iter);
            vectorlist << a->getx() << '\t' << a->gety() << '\t'<< a->getz() << std::endl;
            delete a;
        }
    else { std::cout << outfile_name << " cannot be opened." << std::endl;}
    vectorlist.close();
}
```

My guess is there's just a small syntax thing that I'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: "a nonmember function of a derived class"  What is that?  Classes can't have non-member functions; the definition of a non-member function is that it is not a member.  Do you mean a static member function?

Comment: Nonmember function of a derived class is a bad term for "nonmember function defined in a specific class header/source file". If that means a static member function, then yes, yes I did mean that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dereferencing the pointer so you're passing a const char, not a const char*.

try this:

```
generate_vectorlist(outfile_name);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems:

1. `generate_vectorlist` takes a `const char *`, not a `const char &`.
2. The template type is not in the function signature so the compiler can not deduce the type therefore you need to specify it (using `int` in my example).

So you need to do:

```
generate_vectorlist<int>(outfile_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first bit, try:
    generate_vectorlist(outfile_name);

You should be passing a character pointer, not a character.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the template argument.  There's nothing the compiler can use to deduce what type `T` is.  So you'll have to call it like `generate_vectorlist<MyType>(outfile_name);`, using the appropriate type for `MyType`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
template <class T>
void generate_vectorlist(const char* outfile_name = "input.txt" )
```

The compiler can't deduce the type of T, so it has no idea which `generate_vectorlist` to use.

Call it like this:

```
generate_vectorlist<vectortype>(outfile_name);
```

Though I would actually suggest that this code doesn't make any sense in the first place.